# big streams with DataSnap

Tags: delphi, stream, datasnap

I'm trying to transfer some big streams (~1Mb) between DataSnap server/client but to no avail. I'm trying to understand the code of Jim Tierney (http://blogs.embarcadero.com/jimtierney/2009/04/06/31461) with no luck and i can't even compile the code because of a missing library, anyway ...

The max size of a stream i`m able to receive is 64k, so **any** tips/ideas/code samples you can provide for a *weekend programmer* like me will be very welcomed. Thank you!

**my server code:**

```
function TsrvMethods.getStream(iCount: integer): TStream;
begin
  Result := dummyStream('0123456789', iCount);
end;

function dummyStream(sCnt: string; iCount: integer): TStream;
begin
  Result := TMemoryStream.Create;
  while iCount > 1 do begin
    Result.Write(Pointer(sCnt)^, Length(sCnt));
    Dec(iCount);
  end;
  Result.Seek(0, TSeekOrigin.soBeginning);
end;
```

**my client calling code:**

```
procedure TfrmMain.butStreamClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  sStr : TStream;
begin
  cycleConnection; //make sure we have an active connection

  with TsrvMethodsClient.Create( SQLConn.DBXConnection, False ) do begin
    sStr := getStream( Integer(SpinCount.Value) );
    Free;
  end;
  FreeAndNil(sStr);
end;
```

Comment: What is the problem with this code? Please let us know what the compile time or runtime error is and on what line.

Comment: The code i've posted works ok with streams smaller then 64k. When bigger streams are sent there is no error but the stream is empty on the other side (or is not send/received).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, i think i`ve got it. I'm posting this as an answer maybe somebody else need this.

```
procedure TfrmMain.butStreamClick(Sender: TObject);
const
  iBufSize = 128;
var
  sStr : TStream;
  sMem : TMemoryStream;
  buf: PByte;
  iRead: integer;
begin
  cycleConnection;

  with TsrvMethodsClient.Create( SQLConn.DBXConnection, False ) do begin

    sStr := getStream( 500000 ); //500k stream

    GetMem(buf, iBufSize);
    sMem := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      repeat
        iRead := sStr.Read( Pointer(buf)^, iBufSize);

        if iRead > 0 then sMem.WriteBuffer( Pointer(buf)^, iRead);
        if iRead < iBufSize then break;
      until iRead < iBufSize;
    finally
      FreeMem(buf, iBufSize);
    end;

    Free;
  end;
  FreeAndNil(sStr);
  FreeAndNil(sMem);
end;
```

P.S.

Searching through DataSnap code samples i`ve found that one (speed related) improvement would be to have iBufSize set to 61440 (or equivalent hex value $F000) which seems to be the biggest size can be received in one go. If receiving stream is bigger then reported size will be -1 and the code above is needed to read the entire stream.