# DataSnap ServerMethod functions returned as ftStream parameters being wrongly truncated

Tags: delphi

As DataSnap users will know, its ServerMethods return values to their callers
as DataSnap parameters.

There have been a number of reports on SO and elsewhere relating to a problem with
DataSnap servers returning ServerMethod results as ftStream parameters, that the stream is truncated
prematurely or returned empty. An example is here:
[Can't retrieve TStreams bigger than around 260.000 bytes from a Datasnap Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41854631/cant-retrieve-tstreams-bigger-than-around-260-000-bytes-from-a-datasnap-server/41878153?noredirect=1#comment71904581_41878153)

I have put together a reproducible test case of this that I intend submitting to
Emba's Quality Portal as an MCVE, but before I do I'd like some help pinning down
where the problem occurs.  I'm using Delphi Seattle on Win64, compiling to 32-bits, btw.

My MCVE is completely self-contained (i.e. includes both server and client) and does
not depend on any database data.  Its ServerMethods module contains a function
(`BuildString` in the code below) which returns a string of a caller-specified length
and two ServerMethods `GetAsString` and `GetAsStream` which return the result
as parameters of types ftString and ftStream, respectively.

Its `GetString` method successfully returns a string of any requested length up to
the maximum I've tested, which is 32000000 (32 million) bytes.

Otoh, the `GetStream` method works up to a requested size of 30716; above that,
the returned stream has a size of -1 and is empty.  The expected behaviour of course
that it should be capable of working with much larger sizes, just as `GetString` does.

On the outbound (server) side, at some point the returned stream is passed into
DataSnap's JSon layer en route to the tcp/ip transport layer and on the inbound side, similarly, the stream is retrieved
from the JSon layer.  What I'd like to be able to do, and what this q is about,
is to capture the outbound and inbound JSon representations of the AsStream
parameter value in human-legible form so that I identify whether the unwanted
truncation of its data occurs on the server or client side.  How do I do that?

the reason I'm asking this is that despite hours of looking I've been unable to identify exactly
where the JSon conversions occur.  It's like looking for a needle in a haystack.
If you take a look at the method TDBXJSonStreamWriter.WriteParameter in Data.DBXStream,
the one thing it doesn't write is the stream's contents!

One thing I have been able to establish is regarding line 4809 in Data.DBXStream

```
Size := ((FBuf[IncrAfter(FOff)] and 255) shl 8) or (FBuf[IncrAfter(FOff)] and 255)
```

in the function TDBXRowBuffer.ReadReaderBlobSize.  On entry to
this method, Size is initialised to zero, and it is this line which sets Size to 30716
for all requested stream sizes >= that value.  But I don't know whether this is cause or effect,
i.e. whether the stream trucation has already taken place or whether it's this line
which causes it.

My code is below; apologies for the length of it, but DataSnap projects require
quite a lot of baggage at the best of times and I've included some code which
initialises some of the components to avoid having to post .DFMs too.

ServerMethods code:

```
unit ServerMethods2u;
interface
uses System.SysUtils, System.Classes, System.Json, variants, Windows,
    Datasnap.DSServer, Datasnap.DSAuth, DataSnap.DSProviderDataModuleAdapter;

{$MethodInfo on}
type
  TServerMethods1 = class(TDSServerModule)
  public
    function GetStream(Len: Integer): TStream;
    function GetString(Len: Integer): String;
  end;
{$MethodInfo off}

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses System.StrUtils;

function BuildString(Len : Integer) : String;
var
  S : String;
  Count,
  LeftToWrite : Integer;
const
  scBlock = '%8d bytes'#13#10;
begin
  LeftToWrite := Len;
  Count := 1;
  while Count <= Len do begin
    S := Format(scBlock, [Count]);
    if LeftToWrite >= Length(S) then
    else
      S := Copy(S, 1, LeftToWrite);
    Result := Result + S;
    Inc(Count, Length(S));
    Dec(LeftToWrite, Length(S));
  end;
  if Length(Result) > 0 then
    Result[Length(Result)] := '.'
end;

function TServerMethods1.GetStream(Len : Integer): TStream;
var
  SS : TStringStream;
begin
  SS := TStringStream.Create;
  SS.WriteString(BuildString(Len));
  SS.Position := 0;
  Result := SS;
end;

function TServerMethods1.GetString(Len : Integer): String;
begin
  Result := BuildString(Len);
end;
```

ServerContainer code:

```
unit ServerContainer2u;
interface
uses System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Datasnap.DSTCPServerTransport,
  Datasnap.DSServer, Datasnap.DSCommonServer, Datasnap.DSAuth, IPPeerServer,
  DataSnap.DSProviderDataModuleAdapter;

type
  TServerContainer1 = class(TDataModule)
    DSServer1: TDSServer;
    DSTCPServerTransport1: TDSTCPServerTransport;
    DSServerClass1: TDSServerClass;
    procedure DataModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure DSServerClass1GetClass(DSServerClass: TDSServerClass;
      var PersistentClass: TPersistentClass);
  end;

var
  ServerContainer1: TServerContainer1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses ServerMethods2u;

procedure TServerContainer1.DataModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DSServerClass1.Server := DSServer1;
  DSTCPServerTransport1.Server := DSServer1;
end;

procedure TServerContainer1.DSServerClass1GetClass(
  DSServerClass: TDSServerClass; var PersistentClass: TPersistentClass);
begin
  PersistentClass := TServerMethods1;
end;
```

end.

ServerForm code:

```
unit ServerForm2u;
interface
uses Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,
  Vcl.StdCtrls, DBXJSON, Data.DBXDataSnap, IPPeerClient,
  Data.DBXCommon, Data.FMTBcd, Data.DB, Data.SqlExpr, Data.DbxHTTPLayer,
  DataSnap.DSServer;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    btnGetStream: TButton;
    edStreamSize: TEdit;
    SQLConnection1: TSQLConnection;
    SMGetStream: TSqlServerMethod;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Label1: TLabel;
    btnGetString: TButton;
    Label2: TLabel;
    edStringSize: TEdit;
    SMGetString: TSqlServerMethod;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnGetStreamClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnGetStringClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
  public
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin

  SqlConnection1.ConnectionData.Properties.Values['CommunicationProtocol'] := 'tcp/ip';
  SqlConnection1.ConnectionData.Properties.Values['BufferKBSize'] := '64';

  SMGetStream.Params.Clear;
  SMGetStream.Params.CreateParam(ftInteger, 'Len', ptInput);
  SMGetStream.Params.CreateParam(ftStream, 'Result', ptOutput);

  SMGetString.Params.Clear;
  SMGetString.Params.CreateParam(ftInteger, 'Len', ptInput);
  SMGetString.Params.CreateParam(ftString, 'Result', ptOutput);

end;

procedure TForm1.btnGetStreamClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  SS : TStringStream;
  S : TStream;
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Clear;
  SS := TStringStream.Create;
  try
    SMGetStream.Params[0].AsInteger := StrtoInt(edStreamSize.Text);
    SMGetStream.ExecuteMethod;
    S := SMGetStream.Params[1].AsStream;
    S.Position := 0;
    if S.Size > 0 then begin
      try
        SS.CopyFrom(S, S.Size);
        Memo1.Lines.BeginUpdate;
        Memo1.Lines.Text := SS.DataString;
        Memo1.Lines.Insert(0, IntToStr(S.Size));
      finally
        Memo1.Lines.EndUpdate;
      end;
    end
    else
      ShowMessage(IntToStr(S.Size));
  finally
    SS.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnGetStringClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  S : String;
  Size : Integer;
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Clear;
  Size :=  StrtoInt(edStringSize.Text);
  SMGetString.Params[0].AsInteger := Size;
  SMGetString.ExecuteMethod;
  S := SMGetString.Params[1].AsString;
  if Length(S) > 0 then begin
    try
      Memo1.Lines.BeginUpdate;
      Memo1.Lines.Text := S;
      Memo1.Lines.Insert(0, IntToStr(Length(S)));
    finally
      Memo1.Lines.EndUpdate;
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: See this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1779710/544071
I would suggest this is as designed.

Comment: @Jason It has changed on Delphi 10.1 Berlin. On that answer and Martyn post they say that when a Stream exceeds 32Kb/64kb the received Stream reports a size of -1. While on 10.1 the received Stream shows always the full size, it's just that beyond 255kb is filled by zeroes.

Comment: @MarcGuillot:  Interestingly, I tried the method in the accepted answer to the q Jason linked, and that successfully returns a stream up to the 32M I've tested, without the zero-filling you mentioned.  That answer uses a client-side generated proxy class for the server.  I haven't yet managed to figure out why that works, but calling the server using a TSqlServer method as per my q does not.